# Problem with date an time program in a a dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time, posix

I have been asked for my internship to write a function that runs through a dataframe with date and time and gives back some cells of the rows that are 20h before. 
Attached is a picture of part of the dataframe; ID is the number of the animal, Date is when the animal was seen, Time is the time when the animal was seen (ex:2 stands for 2hour), Lat and Long are the coordinates of the animal.

[image]

Then, the function takes into input (ID, Date+time) and returns the coordinates of where the animal was 20 hours before (columns 4 and 5 of the data frame).

The error message is always the same:

> Error in print(X) : object 'X' not found

It seems like the conditions in the IF clause are never reunited...

Here is the script:

```
data <- data.frame(GPS_data_for_R) #data contains the excel spreadsheet
data$NewTime <- ymd_h(paste(data$Date,as.character(data$Time))) #a new column is created that merge the Date and the Time columns into a POSIXct format

# This function returns the coordinates of the animal 20h before, depending on the ID, Dtae and Time the user wants
Feeding_coordinates <- function (ID, NewTime){
    for ( i in (1:length(data) ) ) {
      if ( data[i,1] == ID & data[i,6] == as.POSIXct(NewTime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")-72000){ #if the ID of the animal matches the request and if the NewTime - 20h also
        data[i,4] <- X #then X takes the value of the Longitude
        data[i,5] <- Y }# and Y the value of the Lagitude
  }
  print (X)
  print (Y)
}
```

I really have no clue why it doesn't work, so any help is very welcomed, I have already spent so much time on it!

Thank you,
Manon.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pictures are neither code nor data unless the topic is image processing. Please click on the "r" below your question, then click on the "info" tab and read up on the tips provided there (some via links) on how to craft a good question that includes real data, all R packages being used and complete (but minimal) reproducible code to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since no (sample) data is provided (yet), it is hard to help you out. However, if your data is structured so that each row resembles one hour, and you want to get the row from 20 hours before, you might want to use `dplyr`'s `lag()`.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
 group_by(ID) %>% # Perhaps optional
 mutate(feed_coord_lat=lag(Lat, 20),
        feef_coord_long=lag(Long, 20))
```

This gives you the whole dataframe with two lagged coordinates columns. You can also build a function out of this.